# Spring Security Saml error decrypting key from SOAP Response - No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl

Tags: java, encryption, saml, saml-2.0, spring-security-saml2

I'm trying to implement SSO with Spring Security SAML but error occurs while decrypting key from SOAP assertion response.
**SOAP response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
   <soap:Body>
      <saml2p:ArtifactResponse xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="ID-067d75bd-3193-4bd8-9852-44da67b015ce" InResponseTo="a590ga841bj851ii498bech5c29h377" IssueInstant="2021-09-29T07:23:59.439Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:alg="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:algsupport" xmlns:coi-naturalperson="http://coi.gov.pl/attributes/naturalperson" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:dsig11="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmldsig11#" xmlns:eidas="http://eidas.europa.eu/saml-extensions" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:mdattr="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:attribute" xmlns:naturalperson="http://eidas.europa.eu/attributes/naturalperson" xmlns:ns13="http://coi.gov.pl/saml-extensions" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" xmlns:xenc11="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#">
         <saml2:Issuer>symulator.login.gov.pl</saml2:Issuer>
         <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#ID-067d75bd-3193-4bd8-9852-44da67b015ce">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds saml2 saml2p xenc"/>
                     </ds:Transform>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
               <ds:X509Data>
                  <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
               </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
         <saml2p:Status>
            <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
         </saml2p:Status>
         <saml2p:Response ID="ID-e15baf95-bfe2-4658-9ffe-097d84b636f3" InResponseTo="a4hj979di081ig2052572agg3f37h29" IssueInstant="2021-09-29T07:23:59.431Z" Version="2.0">
            <saml2:Issuer>symulator.login.gov.pl</saml2:Issuer>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
               <ds:SignedInfo>
                  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256"/>
                  <ds:Reference URI="#ID-e15baf95-bfe2-4658-9ffe-097d84b636f3">
                     <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                           <InclusiveNamespaces xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds saml2 saml2p xenc"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                     </ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                     <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
                  </ds:Reference>
               </ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
               <ds:KeyInfo>
                  <ds:X509Data>
                     <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
                  </ds:X509Data>
               </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <saml2p:Status>
               <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
            </saml2p:Status>
            <saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
               <xenc:EncryptedData Id="_5ef019d753fd9b4faf52138cc8f4d9f0" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
                  <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#aes256-gcm">
                     <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                  </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                  <ds:KeyInfo>
                     <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="_6147c823d9f485f3716099ee5efecdac">
                        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#kw-aes256"/>
                        <ds:KeyInfo>
                           <xenc:AgreementMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#ECDH-ES">
                              <xenc11:KeyDerivationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#ConcatKDF">
                                 <xenc11:ConcatKDFParams AlgorithmID="0000002A687474703A2F2F7777772E77332E6F72672F323030312F30342F786D6C656E63236B772D616573323536" PartyUInfo="0000001673796D756C61746F722E6C6F67696E2E676F762E706C" PartyVInfo="00000018776E696F73656B2E7572706C2D746573742E6E70632E706C">
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                                 </xenc11:ConcatKDFParams>
                              </xenc11:KeyDerivationMethod>
                              <xenc:OriginatorKeyInfo>
                                 <ds:KeyValue>
                                    <dsig11:ECKeyValue>
                                       <dsig11:NamedCurve URI="urn:oid:1.2.840.10045.3.1.7"/>
                                       <dsig11:PublicKey>...</dsig11:PublicKey>
                                    </dsig11:ECKeyValue>
                                 </ds:KeyValue>
                              </xenc:OriginatorKeyInfo>
                           </xenc:AgreementMethod>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
                        <xenc:CipherData>
                           <xenc:CipherValue>...</xenc:CipherValue>
                        </xenc:CipherData>
                     </xenc:EncryptedKey>
                  </ds:KeyInfo>
                  <xenc:CipherData>
                     <xenc:CipherValue>...</xenc:CipherValue>
                  </xenc:CipherData>
               </xenc:EncryptedData>
            </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
         </saml2p:Response>
      </saml2p:ArtifactResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Logs:**

```
2021-09-29 09:24:13.356 DEBUG 3052 --- [ XNIO-2 task-29] o.a.xml.security.algorithms.JCEMapper    : Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#aes256-gcm
2021-09-29 09:24:13.356 DEBUG 3052 --- [ XNIO-2 task-29] o.a.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher    : JCE Key Algorithm: AES
2021-09-29 09:24:15.024 DEBUG 3052 --- [ XNIO-2 task-29] o.a.xml.security.algorithms.JCEMapper    : Request for URI http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#kw-aes256
2021-09-29 09:24:15.024 DEBUG 3052 --- [ XNIO-2 task-29] o.a.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher    : JCE Algorithm = AESWrap
2021-09-29 09:24:16.327 ERROR 3052 --- [ XNIO-2 task-29] org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter    : Error decrypting encrypted key

org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLEncryptionException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.ec.ECPrivateKeyImpl
    at org.apache.xml.security.encryption.XMLCipher.decryptKey(XMLCipher.java:1495)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:708)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptKey(Decrypter.java:639)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptUsingResolvedEncryptedKey(Decrypter.java:794)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToDOM(Decrypter.java:535)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptDataToList(Decrypter.java:453)
    at org.opensaml.xml.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:414)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decryptData(Decrypter.java:141)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.encryption.Decrypter.decrypt(Decrypter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:92)
    ...
```

**Environment:**
Java 1.8 (291), tried on Java 11 and 17 with same result
Spring Boot 1.4.1
spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.10.RELEASE
opensaml-core 4.1.0

**Providers:**

1. sun.security.provider.Sun sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
2. sun.security.ec.SunEC com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
3. com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
4. com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
5. org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
6. sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
7. org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
8. sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI

Comment: surprising. You can just try adding BC provider in class path and also add its entry inside providers list.

Comment: I tried to use Bouncy Castle provider but unfortunatelly still the same error occured

Comment: Okay, try to identify for which certificate the issue is present. You can try saving the certificates from SAMLResponse and import them in sample keystore.  Then try reading them using keytool or Keystore Explorer.